# Approximate Edit distance tree - Exact Edit path

Tags: algorithm, tree, directory, graph-algorithm

I've been looking for an algorithm to efficiently compute an edit path between two trees, a path that does not have to correspond to shortest edit distance but preferably a relatively short one.

The case is that I have two directory trees, consisting of directories and files, and want to compute a sequence of deletes, inserts and renames that will transform one to the other.

I have tried searching both stackoverflow and the wild web but all I find is algorithms for computing shortest edit distance, but they all have high scaling factors.

So my question is, is there any more efficient way then for example "Zhang and Shasha" when I don't need the optimum distance?

Kind regards

Comment: You could heuristically assume that whenever there is a file/dir with the same name in the root of each tree, they correspond to one another.  Recursion takes care of the rest of the tree.  You can find matching filenames between two dirs in O(nlog n) time by sorting then merging, so this will be O(nlog n) overall in the worst case where each tree consists of just a root directory with n files in it.

Comment: Thanks, however, if I understand you correctly this would mean that a moved (renamed) directory would be considered as a delete and a new insert, operations I would like to consider very expensive if it has large files within.

Comment: That's right.  My sugggestion would be to use this approach to grab as much low-hanging fruit as possible, and then fall back on a better algorithm for harder cases.  BTW, write @j_random_hacker (or whatever username) in a comment to notify that person.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you want, but related, is the Robinson-Foulds metric: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson-Foulds_metric

Comment: Thanks again both of you, @j_random_hacker that is a very good idea, although it will fail miserable in some common casessuch as rename of a top level folder. I will give it some thought to see if I can add some additional corresponding heuristics before falling back.

Comment: I am just surprised that there isn't more written on this, I imagine that most bcp and sync services must have something like this to fall back on when they are not live watching file systems..

Comment: You're welcome.  Another idea that might mitigate against renaming: for each bottom-level dir (i.e. each dir with no subdirs) that you have not already confidently matched with the other tree, compute hashes (e.g. MD5) for each file they contain.  Now you can find matching files in these dirs by sorting and merging the hashes (instead of filenames).  After that, you can compute hashes for those dirs themselves by hashing the hashes of their files, then hash the other files in their parent dirs, and repeat on the parent dirs.  IOW use a postorder (bottom-up) DFS to compute hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Klein algorithm](http://grfia.dlsi.ua.es/ml/algorithms/references/editsurvey_bille.pdf) that performs slightly better than "Zhang and Sasha", however it remains of very high complexity in both space and time for practical purpose.

There is an algorithm [here](https://www.cs.york.ac.uk/cvpr/papers/teedit.pdf) that is in fact an heuristic, since the authors misused the term [approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm).
 It reduces the problem to a series of maximum weighted cliques for which it exists several approximation and heuristics, even a greedy approach could here perform reasonably well.

What is true for graphs is true for trees, you could therefore use a [graph kernel convolution approach](http://nlpr-web.ia.ac.cn/2010papers/%E5%BC%80%E6%94%BE%E8%AF%BE%E9%A2%98/%E5%9B%BD%E9%99%85%E5%88%8A%E7%89%A9/Xinbo%20Gao,%20A%20survey%20of%20graph%20edit%20distance.pdf).

If you are looking for an off the shelf implementation (of an unspeficied algorithm, I woudl guess Zhang or Klein), you can check [here](http://www.inf.unibz.it/dis/projects/tree-edit-distance/)